# Hadoop Write/Read an int[] from/into HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to understand how to write and read an int array into/from a file in the HDFS..
since a `int[]` array isn't a `Writable` object, I'm actually using the class `org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable`

So the write task boils down to the following call:

```
new ObjectWritable(int[].class, array).write(arg0);
```

Instead, the read task causes the following:

```
int[] array = {};
new ObjectWritable(int[].class, array).readFields(arg0);
```

I'm not so sure about the last code snippet. In fact if I try to execute it, I get a `NullPointerException` on the second line.

How can I perform correctly a read of an `int[]` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrays of objects you should use the built-in class [ArrayWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html). As the javadoc states you have to subclass it and create a new type like `IntArrayWritable`, which sets the proper class type of the array elements.

Take a look at an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919035/serialization-using-arraywritable-seems-to-work-in-a-funny-way/9726227#9726227) showing how to populate an `IntArrayWritable` in the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the solution of harpun works properly, another question has came to my mind..
This question is more on performances, seen as my application do tons of `int[]` writes and reads..

I think should be more performant the following solution..

WRITE:

```
WritableUtils.writeVInt(out, array.length);
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   WritableUtils.writeVInt(out, array[i]);
```

READ:

```
int[] array = new array[WritableUtils.readVInt(in)];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   array[i] = WritableUtils.readVInt(in);
```

Instead of wrapping it into a IntArrayWritable every time..

WRITE:

```
IntWritable[] a = new IntWritable[array.length];
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
   a[i] = new IntWritable(array[i]);
IntArrayWritable arrayWritable = new IntArrayWritable();
arrayWritable.set(a);
arrayWritable.write(arg0);
```

READ:

```
IntArrayWritable arrayWritable = new IntArrayWritable();
arrayWritable.readFields(arg0);
Writable[] a = arrayWritable.get();
int[] array = new int[a.length];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   array[i] = ((IntWritable)a[i]).get();
```

Isn't it? What do you think about that?