# MapReduce Output ArrayWritable

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, writable

I'm trying to get an output from an ArrayWritable in a simple MapReduce-Task. I found a few questions with a similar problem, but I can't solve the problem in my own code. So I'm looking forward to your help. Thanks :)!

**Input:** Textfile with some sentence.

**Output** should be:

```
<Word, <length, number of same words in Textfile>>
 Example: Hello  5  2
```

The output that I get in my Job is:

```
hello WordLength_V01$IntArrayWritable@221cf05
test WordLength_V01$IntArrayWritable@799e525a
```

I think the problem is in the subclass from IntArrayWritable, but I don't get the right correction to fix this. By the way we have Hadoop 2.5 and I use the following code to get this result:

**Main Method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word length V1");

    // Set Classes
    job.setJarByClass(WordLength_V01.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    // job.setCombinerClass(MyReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    // Set Output and Input Parameters
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntArrayWritable.class);

    // Number of Reducers
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    // Set FileDestination
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

**Mapper:**

```
public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    // Initialize Variables
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    // Map Method
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Use Tokenizer
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

        // Select each word
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());

            // Output Pair
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntArrayWritable> {

    // Initialize Variables
    private IntWritable count = new IntWritable();
    private IntWritable length = new IntWritable();

    // Reduce Method
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Count Words
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }

        count.set(sum);

        // Wordlength
        length.set(key.getLength());

        // Define Output
        IntWritable[] temp = new IntWritable[2];
        IntArrayWritable output = new IntArrayWritable(temp);

        temp[0] = count;
        temp[1] = length;

        // Output
        output.set(temp);
        context.write(key, new IntArrayWritable(output.get()));
    }
}
```

**SubClass**

```
public static class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public IntArrayWritable(IntWritable[] intWritables) {
        super(IntWritable.class);
    }

    @Override
    public IntWritable[] get() {
        return (IntWritable[]) super.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        for(IntWritable data : get()){
            data.write(arg0);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the following links to find a solution:

- [Interface Writable (hadoop.apache.org)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html)
- [Class ArrayWritable (hadoop.apache.org)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html)
- [stackoverflow.com (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919035/serialization-using-arraywritable-seems-to-work-in-a-funny-way)
- [stackoverflow.com (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810550/output-a-list-from-a-hadoop-map-reduce-job-using-custom-writable)

I'm really thankful for any idea!

**-------- Solution --------**

New SubClass:

```
public static class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {

    public IntArrayWritable(IntWritable[] values) {
        super(IntWritable.class, values);
    }

    @Override
    public IntWritable[] get() {
        return (IntWritable[]) super.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        IntWritable[] values = get();
        return values[0].toString() + ", " + values[1].toString();
    }
}
```

New Reduce Method:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Count Words
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }

        count.set(sum);

        // Wordlength
        length.set(key.getLength());

        // Define Output
        IntWritable[] temp = new IntWritable[2];
        temp[0] = count;
        temp[1] = length;

        context.write(key, new IntArrayWritable(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks perfect. Just you need to write one more method printStrings() in your **subclass** that returns a string instead of array . In built toString() will return array of strings thats the reason it is giving address in your output instead of values.

```
public String printStrings() {
     String strings = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         strings = strings + " "+ values[i].toString();
       }
      return strings;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this solution doesn't work for me. I have the same output like before.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you for your hint :)! I added the new code.